# What can I use in place of setContentView when converting an Activity to a Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, setcontentview

I am trying to convert an Activity to a fragment as follows:

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    public void scanBarcode(View view) {
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(HomeActivity.this);
        scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerResultHandler());
        setContentView(scannerView);
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }

    private class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            String resultCode = result.getText();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            scannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_warrant, container, false);

        Button scanBar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_barcode);
        scanBar.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.scan_barcode:
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
                scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerResultHandler());
//                setContentView(scannerView);
                scannerView.startCamera();
                break;
        }
    }

    class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            String resultCode = result.getText();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
            scannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    }
}
```

**warranty_fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kainet.barcode.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan_barcode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Scan"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see the buttonClick calls the scannerView and returns to the view when it has captured the barcode, and this is achieved using the setContentView. But it seems like fragments don't support setContentView. What is the alternative or how can I get this code to work?

Comment: Look at my answer over here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340778/how-to-call-setcontentview-in-a-fragment/44341107#44341107

Comment: Use another fragment ...

Comment: how? I am just call the scannerView and return to the fragment when I have capture the barcode.

Comment: `setContentView` is taken care by `onCreateView` in fragment

Comment: did you notice the commented out lines, can I call onCreateView the same way I call setContentView?

Comment: can you post  your R.layout.fragment_warrant file?

Comment: added R.layout.fragment_warrant file